# Plot a graph with an uncertain number of tangents

Tags: plotting, syntax

The code below tries to illustrate a graph ($y=(2-x^3)/x$) that can have 1-3 tangents depending on the tangent point $a$.

```
y[x_] := (2 - x^3)/x
a = -0.5;
p = Plot[y[x], {x, -10, 10}];
x0 = x /. NSolve[y'[x] == y'[a], x]
l1[x_] := y'[x0[[1]]] (x - x0[[1]]) + y[x0[[1]]] // Simplify
l2[x_] := y'[x0[[2]]] (x - x0[[2]]) + y[x0[[2]]] // Simplify
l3[x_] := y'[x0[[2]]] (x - x0[[3]]) + y[x0[[3]]] // Simplify
p1 = Plot[l1[x], {x, -10, 10}];
p2 = Plot[l2[x], {x, -10, 10}];
p3 = Plot[l3[x], {x, -10, 10}];
Show[p, p1, p2, p3]
```

Is there a better way to write this? The code 'work' as `Mathematica` ignores any missing solutions, but it would be 'nice' to have a code that is more 'logical' and efficient, especially for graphs that might have even more tangents, e.g. 5+ tangents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Prepend[y'[#] (x - #) + y[#] & /@ x0, y[x]]], {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]